# FFT MATLAB code correct?

Tags: matlab, fft

I'd like to generate the frequency spectrum of seven concatenated cosine functions.

I am unsure whether my code is correct; in particular, whether N = time*freq*7 is correct, or whether it should be N = time*freq (without the times seven).

My code is as follow:

```
sn = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
time = 1;
freq = 22050;
N = time*freq*7;
dt = 1/freq;

t = 0 : dt : time - dt;

y = @(sn, phasePosNeg) cos(2*pi*(1200-100*sn) * t + phasePosNeg * sn*pi/10);

f = [y(sn(1), 1), y(sn(2), -1), y(sn(3), 1), y(sn(4), -1), y(sn(5), 1), y(sn(6), -1), y(sn(7), 1)];
F = abs(fftshift(fft(f)))/N;

df = freq/N;
faxis = -freq/2 : df : (freq/2-1/freq);

plot(faxis, F);
grid on;
axis([-1500, 1500, 0, 0.6]);
title('Frequency Spectrum Of Concatenated Cosine Functions');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Magnitude');
```

I suppose the essense of my question is:
Should the height of the spikes equal 1/7 of 0.5, or simply 0.5?  (All cosine functions have an amplitude of 1.)

Thank you.

Comment: The result of this code is what it is. I'm not sure what the question is; does the result not match your expectation?

Comment: Sort of, I'm not sure if ive correctly calculated te frequency spectrum of the concatenated cos function because I'm not sure whether N should equal 7*time*freq or just time*freq.

Comment: Why are you *concatenating* these different waveforms ? You will get horrible discontinuities every 1s when the frequency/phase changes. Also the FFT will be somewhat meaningless if you take it over the entire 7 seconds as (a) the signal is not stationary (b) the discontinuities will generate a lot of artefacts. I'm wondering if what you really wanted to do was *combine* (i.e. *add*) these 7 different frequency components, which would make a lot more sense ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I totall agree with what you're saying.  The task was to add the seven an get the spectrum, and then to concatenate the seven and get te spectrum.  Then to compare te spectrum and 'notice' that they are the same; however, I don't get the same spectrum if I use N = freq*time*7, so I'm wondering if that is correct.  I should add that I do get the same spectrum, if I change N to equal freq*time; however I don't think this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly homework, so I'm just going to give some direction:
 In the concatenated case, think of it as though you're adding six waveforms, which are each padded by zeros (6x the length of the waveform), and then offset these so they don't overlap and then added together to form the concatenated waveform.  In the case where you're adding the FFTs of the individual waveforms, also remember that you're assuming that they are periodic.  So you basically need to handle the zero padding so that you're comparing apples to apples.  One check, of course, is to just use one waveform throughout and make sure it works in this case (and this should return exactly the same result since the FFT assumes that waveform is periodic -- that is, infinitely concatenated to itself).

Thinking of this in terms of [Parseval's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) will probably be helpful in figuring out how to interpret and normalize things.

It is correct to use `N=(7*time)*freq`, since your actual time of the waveform is `7*time`, regardless of how you constructed it.

Several of the comments talk about discontinuities, but it should be noted that these usually exist in the FFT anyway, since the FFT waveform is assumed to be periodic, and that usually means that there are effectively discontinuities at the boundaries even in the non-concatenated case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've actually plotted them and everything.  I know how to do that.  The issue is, I don't get the same spectra for adding as I do when I concatenate them.  But the question sas that I should.  The reason I don't get the same spectrum is because the time interval  changes for concatenating them.  My problem is, the lecturer says the spectra should be exactly the same, but I don't think they should and I'm a bit stuck.  Myain question was if n should equal 7xfreqxtime which you answered, implying that the lecture is incorrect for I believe she only divided by time*freq.

Comment: I think the best way to understand this is to, instead of concatenating 7 different waveforms, concatenate 7 identical waveforms.  Then it's clear that the FFT should the exactly the same (since the FFT assumes that the waveform is periodic, the waveforms from the perspective of the FFT really are identical).  Are these the same, and if they are not, then why not?

Comment: Also, btw, it's worth considering that "by the same", your instructor may have meant that they are the same to within a constant multiplicative factor.  Depending on the context, this could really be the case.  (In general, it's important to get the magnitude of the FFT correct, but very, very commonly it's really considered important, even in published papers for example, they won't put units on the axis, making the actual values fairly meaningless), so that it wouldn't be at all unusual to mean within a constant scale factor.  Still, it seems worth getting it right anyway.

Comment: Yes, I did actually think of this; I actually asked her about this and she said that they at the same (exactly) and showed my her plots.  I said that I reckon her magnitudes should be 1/7 of 0.5 for the concatenation; however, she just disagreed, saying the period is one second and not seven...  Which just sounds ridiculous...

Comment: Did you try concatenating identical waveforms, and do you see why these two results should turn out the same? There's always a questions of how one normalizes things, in terms of energy density or total energy, for example, but if normalized and interpreted correctly, the results should turn out with the same. When questioning this type of thing, I usually find it helpful to also consider Parseval's theorem, and think about what terms you're summing for both the normal waveform and the FFT.

Comment: I don't see why concatenating the same waveforms together will result in exaclty the same spectrum as adding them.  Adding the waveforms together increases the amplitude of the waveform.  Concatenating them doesn't.  So I figure that the spikes will be shorter for the concatenation than for the summation.  Furthermore, this is reflected in MATLAB by the fact that the FFT(x) result is to be divided by N.  If x is the concatenated waves, N will need to be seven times larger than if x were the summed cosine waves.  Is my line of reasoning incorrect?

Comment: The power in the concatenated waveform is the same as the power in the summed waveforms, so the total power in the transform is also the same.  There are more frequencies represented in the concatenated waveform, so in this sense they'll never be "exactly the same".  I know of no canonical way to represent the FFT, sometime it's R and I, sometimes it's magnitude, sometimes people divide by N and sometimes they don't.  You are dividing by N, but if there's a comparison where you don't divide by N that works better for you, it's fair not to as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let me correct/help you on a few things:

1) the fourier transform is typically displayed in dB for its magnitute. 20*log base10(FFT coeff)
2) there is no need to divide your FFT amplitudes by any value of N.

```
F = abs(fftshift(fft(f)))/N; %get rid of the N or N =1
```

3) if N is the number of points in your FFT N = size(t); because you've taken that many samples of the sin/cos functions

4)  When plotting the function remember that the FFT spans from -Pi to + Pi and you need to remap it to the frequency spectrum using your sampling frequency

5) becasue of the large phase discontinuties between these functions, dont expect the forrier transform the be a bunch of large narrow peaks. (otherwise Phase Modulation would be the modulationscheme of choice... zero bandwidth)

Comment: I'm plotting a double side spectra on an evely spaced scale (not decibel/logrythmic).  I don't understand why I wouldn't divide by N, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Adam: given that the OP is having difficulty getting the magnitude of the FFT correct, there's no real advantage, and a whole lot of addittion complication, to then do 20*log10 (and although this is common, especially in perceptual acoustics, it's certainly not the only meaningful way to report the magnitude of the FFT).